# Keyboard shortcut to remove empty lines in a C# code file

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to remove empty lines in C# code files (.cs)?

Similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>D</kbd> which formats the whole .cs file.

Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the Find and Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>). Search for

```
\n\n
```

and replace with

```
\n
```

using regular expressions (expand the Find Options section to enable).

If you want to remove lines containing nothing but whitespace you could try searching for

```
\n\s*\n+
```

Comment: Rinse and repeat till no more replaces.  You might wanna do `\n\n+`.

Answer (score 5):

[CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) has a setting that automatically removes empty lines (when you save the file, I think) according to some configurable rules. I think it makes the files quite neat.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any. You can use a separate refactoring add-in to automate this, such as [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper).

Comment: Don't use a tank to kill a mosquito!

Answer (score 2):

In the Visual Studio options, under Text Editor -> General, there's an option "Apply Cut and Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection".  If you check this, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> will remove a blank line.